# How to add commas for the thousands place using htmlhelper

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc

I am working on a project that works with large numbers that I'm pulling in from SQL, reading to a list, and outputting to a grid using HTML Helper. Right now I'm trying to add commas to my numbers but I haven't been able to find any resources online that would explain a way to do that. Sorry, I'm kind of a beginner at this but I can answer questions if it helps to clarify. This is where I'm at:

```
<td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.mbs.Original_Balance)</td>
<td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.mbs.Collateral_Factor)</td>
<td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.mbs.Current_Balance)</td>
```

Essentially, I'm asking how I would add commas to these so that the numbers display as "1,234,567"

Answer (score 4):

Add the `DisplayFormat` attribute to the model, like this:

```
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "N")]
public ... Original_Balance ..
```

Comment: It might be `N0` if you want to avoid `.00` at the end of the formatted output.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! I am a little unsure where to put this in the model...

Comment: @JimmyLive, you add this to the properties that you want that format on. In other words, you attribute or decorate the `Original_Balance` *property* in the model.

Answer (score 1):

Use ToString("0.00") or any of the many available format strings:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: value.toString("N");